# Set field value in custom list when the task is completed :workflow in MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, workflow, task-list

I have two lists one is my custom list named: Calender and another is task list named CalendarTasks.
I've set workflow on Calender which gets fired on item added in that list. I'm using Assign To Do action, it adds the entry in CalenderTasks list. 
Till this it works perfect! 
Now, I want something like this:
When user completes the task, I want to update a field in CalendarTasks.
I've tried but could not find a way to deal with this.
Any suggestions will be appriciated.
I know its easy in 2010, but I am working in MOSS- sharepoint 2007.

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 1):

You can add workflow on tasks list. Set it to start when item changed. In this workflow check if task is completed, then set field value in your list.

There is 'Related Item ID' field in the Tasks list. It is Id of the source item on which the task was created. You can check task status, get item by 'Related Item ID' and change it.

Comment: So you are saying to create another workflow on Task list?Which will be fired on Task list item changed and will check for status. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I added more details in my answer above. Review it.